# set web hook with self sign certificate for telegram bot

Tags: c#, telegram, telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

recently telegram added a new future to support the self sign certificates. now i want to set a web hook with my self sign certificate but i have no idea how. how can send my certificate to the telegram?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [this section](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks#setting-a-verified-webhook-with-an-untrusted-root) of official guide, it use simple curl command.